# Edit CoreData from detailView

Tags: iphone, core-data

The program is very simple: it has a masterView and a detailView. In the detail view I should be able to edit the attributes from the corresponding object (basically adding a number to the already stored number). The problem is that I'm not sure how to save the changes.
I have this in an IBAction in the detailViewController:

```
- (IBAction)depositFunds:(id)sender
{
     float change = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"balance"] floatValue] + [amountTextfield.text floatValue];
     [self.detailItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:change] forKey:@"balance"];
}
```

How can I save those changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried importing the managedObjectContext from the masterView and saving it. It worked.
Do this, import the context:

```
- (void) setManagedObject:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObject
{
     managedObjectContext = managedObject;
}
```

Pass the context through either the segue method or didSelectRowAtIndex method.

```
myDetailViewController *viewC = [segue destinationViewController];
[viewC setManagedObject:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Then add this to your saving method.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Cheers!